# How to use LastModifiedTime in KeywordQuery?

Tags: keywordquery

I've been using FullTextSQLQuery or Search Web Service in my custom search solution till today. Wanted to explore **KeywordQuery** but usage of 'LastModifiedTime' in query doesn't return search results.

code snippet:

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup.Default,
                SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier.Default);

SearchServiceApplicationProxy ssap = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy))
                    as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
using (KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(ssap))
{
query.QueryText = "IsDocument:1 Filename:\"Test*\" Path:\"http://sp2010vm/Shared Documents/*\" (LastModifiedTime > '2011/04/25 05:00:00 PM' AND LastModifiedTime <= '2011/04/26 06:00:00 PM')";
...
```

Removing LastModifiedTime check works perfectly. How to include LastModifiedTime criteria?
Also,is there a way to simulate Filename LIKE 'Test%' behavior using KeywordQuery?
Neither Filename:"Test%" nor Filename:"Test*" works this way.

--Praveen

Comment: Any help on this? Does KeywordQuery support Filename:"Test%" or Filename:"Test*"?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing query to:

```
query.QueryText = "IsDocument:1 Filename:\"Test*\" Path:\"http://sp2010vm/Shared Documents/*\" (LastModifiedTime:\"2011-04-25..2011-04-26\")";
```

You cannot filter on time in SharePoint keyword queries. It is ignored (per design i guess)

For completeness: You can also choose to use the "internal" property write: instead of LastModifiedTime